# Weblogic Deployment Unable to Resolve Local Queue

Tags: jms, jndi, weblogic-10.x, spring-jms

We have a spring-based application that is failing to deploy on a Weblogic 10.3 container. Upon deployment, the application attempts to look up two local JMS queues  within the Weblogic container's JMS module and, when the deployment takes place, the application locates one local queue okay but not the other.

Both queues are configured exactly the same except for their names are different. Why does the application locate one queue okay but not the other???

I've checked queue names JNDI names many times over and I can't see any spelling errors or anything like that.

I have turned trace logging on and I can see that the connection factory used to look up both queues is the same, the spring JMS configuration is exactly the same for both queues yet one it finds the other it does not.

I don't know what else to check to establish what the problem might be... any ideas?

This is the error I get when it fails to look up one of the queues in the Weblogic JNDI tree:

`Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'QUEUE_NAME'. Resolved ''; remaining name 'QUEUE_NAME'
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.newNameNotFoundException(BasicNamingNode.java:1139)`

PS: Both queues have the same Subdeployment and same Targets configured.

---- edited to add artifact's Spring XML Configuration snippet below ----

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang 
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company.service" />

    <bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
        <property name="environment">
            <props>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- this is the Message Driven POJO (MDP) -->
    <bean id="messageListener" class="com.company.service.controller.ServiceJMSListener" />
    <!-- this is the message listener container -->
    <bean id="jmsContainer"
        class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="queueConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="destination" ref="inboundQueue" />
        <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" />
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" />
    </bean>
    <!-- JNDI Connection Factory -->
    <bean id="queueConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="jndiTemplate" />
        </property>
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>SERVICE_QCF</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- Queue to listen to -->
    <bean id="inboundQueue" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="jndiTemplate" />
        </property>
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>QUEUE_A</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="outboundQueue" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="jndiTemplate" />
        </property>
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>QUEUE_B</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="queueTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <ref bean="queueConnectionFactory" />
        </property>
        <property name="destinationResolver">
            <ref bean="jmsDestinationResolver" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsDestinationResolver"
        class="org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JndiDestinationResolver">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="jndiTemplate" />
        </property>
        <property name="cache">
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you have a look to the JDNI tree in your running server to check if the queue is created or not, and to which jndi name it is bound to ? Use the admin console for this purpose.

Comment: The queues are in a jms module on a Weblogic Server (Jms) separate to the Weblogic Server (App) where the artifact is failing to deploy. The Weblogic Admin Server manages both the JMS and App Weblogic servers. Now, using the Admin console I can go to the JMS Weblogic Server and view its JNDI tree. In the JNDI tree I can see both queues that the artifact tries to connect to (One successfully, the other one not at all). Both queues in the JNDI tree show that the Binding Names of the queues are just like the queue names themselves. Still, the deployment can see only one of the queues.

Comment: Can you post the code running in your application trying to connect to the jms server .

Comment: I understand that you have 2 WebLogic server instances, not part of a cluster. Then, you need to set the url for the application to be able to connect to the jndi tree in the jms server :

Comment: `<prop key="java.naming.provider.url">${provider.url}</prop>`

Comment: I think I have already tried a configuration with "java.naming.provider.url" prop set and still the same result. But I will try again however just to double-check. By the way, if the deployment wasn't able to connect to the JNDI tree altogether then, shouldn't the deployment be failing to connect to both queues instead of just one?

Comment: I have deleted the old deployment and tried deploying fresh again with `<prop key="java.naming.provider.url">${provider.url}</prop>` as you suggested and this time the deployment has gone `Active` which means its started okay. I am sure the deployment ear originally had that prop enabled though so I must have been deploying the wrong ear maybe? Anyway, human error I guess and not Weblogic playing up.